# C# prompting for a boolean value

Tags: c#, boolean

My searches have come up blank, or I am just not understand the results that I am finding. I am trying to prompt the user to input a boolean value, but I want the answer to be yes or no. Let me know if you need to see more code but I have this for the prompt.

```
public static bool getBoolInputValue(string inputType)
    {
        bool valid = false;
        bool value = true;
        string inputString = string.Empty;
        do
        {
            inputString = GetInput(inputType);
            if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputString)))
            {
                valid = bool.TryParse(inputString, out value);
            }
            if (!valid)
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid " + inputType + " try again!");
        } while (!valid);

        return value;
    }
```

This is the paramater for my boolean. Maybe this needs to be more specific?

```
public bool Nitrus
    {
        set { nitrus = value; }
        get { return nitrus; }
    }
```

Thank you for the help. I am fairly new to programming but cannot figure this out. It does prompt successfully, but it does not matter what answer I put into the box, it tells me it is not the right format.

Comment: Skip the `IsNullOrEmpty` test, `bool.TryParse` is smart enough to return false if you pass in an empty string.

Comment: I don't understand why someone would vote this question down (I've upvoted).  We all had to start somewhere and that includes developing our own skills to find answers to our problems, whether that be on MSDN or somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the user to type in "yes" and that will mean you have a True value. If that is correct, skip all the `string.IsNullOrEmpty` and `bool.TryParse` stuff and do something more like this.

```
//make it ToLower so that it will still match if the user inputs "yEs"
inputString = GetInput(inputType);
if (inputString.ToLower() == "yes")
{
  value = true;
}
else
{
  value = false;
}

//note that the if/else code is the same as directly applying 
// the value from the comparison itself:
// value = inputString.ToLower() == "yes";

// this allows the user to type in "yes" or "y":
// value = inputString.ToLower() == "yes" || inputString.ToLower() == "y";
```

Comment: Microsoft's guidelines for use of .NET strings call for using ToUpper rather than ToLower, though it's probably better just to specify a case-insensitive comparison if that's the desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you, this works. However my program continually prompts me for the question lol. Its obviously not liking the answer for some reason. Onto the next problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your program will only accept 'true' or 'false' as valid boolean values. If you want 'yes' or 'no', then you will need to do a string comparison.

```
valid = string.Compare(inputString, "yes", true) == 0 || string.Compare(inputString, "no", true) == 0;

...
value = string.Compare(inputString, "yes", true) == 0;
```

Comment: `? true : false` is always redundant.

Comment: No worries, I'm tired too, just stayed up all night playing a 16-hour Axis and Allies game :)

Answer (score 0):

[`Boolean.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse.aspx) only recognizes "True" and "False".  For "Yes" and "No` or "On" and "Off", you need to write your own function.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool getBoolInputValue()
{
    bool value;
    bool valid;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter yes or no: ");
        var inputString = Console.ReadLine();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputString))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if ( string.Equals(inputString, "yes")
        {
           value = true;
           valid = true;
        }
        else if ( string.Equals(inputString, "no")
        {
           value = false;
           valid = true;
        }

    } while (!valid);

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this won't compile because `valid` is uninitialized. ie, if the input string is "jimmy crack corn" to start.

Answer (score 0):

```
main()
{
    bool bIsLifeGood = TakeUserBooleanInput("Is life good? [Y/N]: ");
}

private static bool TakeUserBooleanInput(string inputMsgPrompt)
{
    bool bUserBooleanInput = false;
    bool validInputCollected = false;

    do
    {
        try
        {
            Console.Write(inputMsgPrompt);
            bUserBooleanInput = ParseUserBooleanInput(Console.ReadLine());
            validInputCollected = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            validInputCollected = false;
        }

    } while (validInputCollected == false);

    return bUserBooleanInput;
}

private static bool ParseUserBooleanInput(string temp)
{
    bool bReturn = false;
    string tmpLower = temp.ToLower().Trim();
    switch (tmpLower)
    {
        case "yes":
            bReturn = true;
            break;

        case "y":
            bReturn = true;
            break;

        case "true":
            bReturn = true;
            break;

        case "no":
            bReturn = false;
            break;

        case "n":
            bReturn = false;
            break;

        case "false":
            bReturn = false;
            break;

        default:
            bReturn = bool.Parse(tmpLower);
            break;

    }

    return bReturn;
}
```